# Make a app that allow user to download video from different sites

Tags: ios, app-store

Is this possible to download video from different site directly. I wanna know, is their any restriction from Apple to make a app that able to download any video from any site. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes their is restriction from apple to make an app that able to download any video from any site without its permission. you have to provide document that confirm you are and your application allow to download videos other wise your application wont accept by apple.

You need to provide evidence to apple during your application submission that have to mention your app allow to download contain from site.

Apple Reject by this response:

> From Apple
>
> 8.6 - Apps that include the ability to save or download music or video content from third party sources (e.g. Apple Music, YouTube, SoundCloud, Vimeo, etc) without explicit authorization from those sources will be rejected

Comment: is this possible to get document from any video site.

Comment: for that you need to contact the particular site owner for get document :P

Answer (score 0):

I think if your app alerts the user that's ok.

Comment: Nope that wont allow with this you have to provide some doc to prove that your app eligible to download contain from that site and that you need to submit during app submission.

Answer (score 0):

you can download video in your doucment dir if you have video in your dropbox url. and make it public to save video , Thanks